# Generate a graph in html and save as image

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I want to generate a graph using certain values and capture/save the output as jpeg/png. I'm generating a graph using google charts and capturing using html2canvas. Following is the code i am trying.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          },
          bars: 'horizontal' 
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    $(document).ready(function() {
    html2canvas($("#barchart_material"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(myImage);
        }
    });
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="barchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Google graph works fine and also the opening of image captured, as a separate code, but when i merge both it doesn't. 
And also, my objective is to SAVE the image locally and not just open.

Comment: did you try removing window.open(myImage); so that image is not opened

Comment: @user93 Yes i did try it, But just to confirm if the html2canvas is working i have put window.open

Comment: it seems that html2canvas does not work properly with google graph. Did you try chart.getUrI() method to get the image

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a lot of hassle and don't use the interactive Google Charts API.  Use the image-based charting instead.

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/bar_charts

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But i'm looking for the image saving part as discussed in my question.

Comment: @umzee The thing is, all these `html2canvas` libraries are hacks.  They don't really work in a way that you'd expect, and there are often side effects.  You're probably running into one.  If you switch to an image-based chart, you don't have to do anything.